# The jquery.fileupload plugin causes require.js to randomly fail imports

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jquery-file-upload

I'm using require.js and have a page with an from that used jquery.fileupload. After introducing the plugin I now see some files fail to be imported before the define call back is executed. This causes random errors where the libraries can't find their dependencies. It's as though require.js is moving on before all the dependencies can be resolved.

I've followed these instructions:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-use-jQuery-File-Upload-with-RequireJS

But beyond that it's a very vanilla install. I'm using the minified versions of libraries where possible. Any insight is welcome.

here's the main.js:

```
(function () {                                                                          
  'use strict';                                                                         

  require.config({                                                                      
    baseUrl: '/js',                                                                     
    waitSeconds: 800,                                                                   
    paths: {                                                                            
      jquery: ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min',               
        'lib/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min'],                                                 
      'jquery.fileupload': 'lib/jquery.fileupload/jquery.fileupload',                   
      'jquery.fileupload-ui': 'lib/jquery.fileupload/jquery.fileupload-ui',             
      'jquery.fileupload-image': 'lib/jquery.fileupload/jquery.fileupload-image',       
      'jquery.fileupload-validate': 'lib/jquery.fileupload/jquery.fileupload-validate', 
      'jquery.fileupload-video': 'lib/jquery.fileupload/jquery.fileupload-video',       
      'jquery.fileupload-audio': 'lib/jquery.fileupload/jquery.fileupload-audio',       
      'jquery.fileupload-process': 'lib/jquery.fileupload/jquery.fileupload-process',   
      'jquery.ui.widget': 'lib/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.widget',                             
      'jquery.iframe-transport': 'lib/jquery.iframe-transport/jquery.iframe-transport', 
      'load-image': 'lib/load-image/load-image.min',                                    
      'load-image-meta': 'lib/load-image/load-image-meta',                              
      'load-image-exif': 'lib/load-image/load-image-exif',                              
      'load-image-ios': 'lib/load-image/load-image-ios',                                
      'canvas-to-blob': 'lib/canvas-to-blob/canvas-to-blob.min',                        
      tmpl: 'lib/tmpl/tmpl.min',                                                        
      bootstrap: 'lib/bootstrap/bootstrap',                                             
      bootstrapTab: 'lib/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab',                                      
      EventEmitter: 'lib/event_emitter/EventEmitter',                                   
      linkedin: ['//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true',                            
        'http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true'],                               
      skinny: 'lib/skinny/skinny',                                                      
      selectize: 'lib/selectize/selectize.min',                                         
      sifter: 'lib/sifter/sifter',                                                      
      microplugin: 'lib/microplugin/microplugin.min'                                    
    },                                                                                  

    shim: {                                                                             
      bootstrap: {                                                                      
        deps: ['jquery'],                                                               
      },                                                                                
      bootstrapTab: {                                                                   
        deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],                                                  
      },                                                                                
      linkedin: {                                                                       
        exports: 'IN'                                                                   
      },                                                                                
      selectize: {                                                                      
        deps: ['jquery', 'sifter', 'microplugin']                                       
      },                                                                                
      'jquery.iframe-transport': {                                                      
        deps: ['jquery']                                                                
      }                                                                                 
    }                                                                                   
  });                                                                                   
  require(['app'], function (App) {                                                     
    App.initialize();                                                                   
  });                                                                                   
}());
```

And the from code:

```
define([], function () {
  'use strict';

  return function () {
    require(['jquery', 'tmpl', 'load-image', 'canvas-to-blob',
  'jquery.iframe-transport', 'jquery.fileupload-ui'], function ($) {

      $('#product').fileupload({
        url: '/products/create'
      });
    });
  };
});
```

The module gets called after the page has been loaded.

It's also worth noting that all files are downloaded successfully. No 404's, etc.

Comment: Can you show us your code which cause the problem (with link to your exact libraries) or reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: I have used jquery-file-upload with no problem at all with requirejs. perhaps you can show your require.config and the code?

Comment: @mallim This is good to know. I'll post the offending code, I'm sure it's just something I'm overlooking.

Comment: @Fractaliste Here's the code, let me know if I can provide anything else. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Is your JavaScript code alone on that page or is something else also loading jQuery? If the latter, it could be the explanation for your troubles.

Comment: @Louis Actually, I just figured it out as of this moment. There is a flaw in the minified version of load-image.js. I can't be positive yet if there is an over all flaw in the jquery.fileupload ecosystem as far as dependency chains go (like, is it because it's a slightly larger file that it happens to create the right timing, or is it actually a bad dependency chain some how).

I get no errors at all when I use the unminified version. Super frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a flaw in the minified version of load-image.js that breaks how the dependencies load. I don't have exact proof as to why, it could be the smaller size causes a race condition, or it could be something weird in that particular file. What I do know is the minified version causes the random errors and the normal version does not (this is off master so I suppose I was taking a risk).

I raised a [flag here](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/issues/40)

EDIT: it turns out the minified version of the plugin includes all the extensions which explains the odd dependency behavior.

Comment: What did you end up doing to solve this with the .min version?

Comment: I removed all the references to the extensions and dependencies. I now just include the 'jquery.fileupload-ui' file. Everything is minified in.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer from [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277250/matt) is the best solution in this case. Thanks a million, it save us a lot of time.
In requirejs.config, you have to add the load-image dependecies separatly - file by file. 
For example:

```
require.config({
        'jquery.ui.widget' : 'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget',            
        'jquery.fileupload':'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/jquery.fileupload',
        'jquery.fileupload-ui': 'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/jquery.fileupload-ui',
        'jquery.fileupload-image': 'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/jquery.fileupload-image',
        'jquery.fileupload-validate':'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/jquery.fileupload-validate',
        'jquery.fileupload-audio':'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/jquery.fileupload-audio',
        'jquery.fileupload-video':'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/jquery.fileupload-video',
        'jquery.fileupload-process': 'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/jquery.fileupload-process',
        'jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui': 'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui',
        'jquery.iframe-transport': 'lib/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.2/js/jquery.iframe-transport',
        'load-image':'lib/load-image-1.10.0',
        'load-image-meta':'lib/load-image-meta-1.10.0',
        'load-image-ios':'lib/load-image-ios-1.10.0',
        'load-image-exif':'lib/load-image-exif-1.10.0',
        'canvas-to-blob':'lib/canvas-to-blob-2.0.5',
        'tmpl':'lib/tmpl.2.4.1'
    }
});
```

call in html site:

```
requirejs(['jquery',
            'jquery.ui.widget',
            'tmpl',
            'load-image',
            'jquery.iframe-transport',
            'jquery.fileupload-ui'], function () {
                $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                    url: 'photo-upload.html'
            });
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility modify the shim:

```
   shim: {                                                                             
      bootstrap: {                                                                      
        deps: ['jquery'],                                                               
      },                                                                                
      bootstrapTab: {                                                                   
        deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],                                                  
      },                                                                                
      linkedin: {                                                                       
        exports: 'IN'                                                                   
      },                                                                                
      selectize: {                                                                      
        deps: ['jquery', 'sifter', 'microplugin']                                       
      },                                                                                
      'jquery.iframe-transport': {                                                      
        deps: ['jquery']                                                                
      },
      'jquery.fileupload-ui':{
        deps: ['jquery']   
      }
```

Another option downgrade jquery to 1.X (this is because the sample page is using jquery 1.X)

Comment: The version of jquery shouldn't be the issue here. The plugin actually works just fine, but randomly not all of the dependencies are loaded before it executes the callback in the `require()`.

Comment: I still get errors like this:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload' on every few visits to the page.